# Is there a newer User Interface for the login screen when using JSP created by - userService.createLoginURL(req.getRequestURI())?

Tags: google-app-engine

I recently switched from using the Javascript API to JSP.

The login screen users were redirected to in the Javascript API as well as the one shown in the Dev Console under "APIs and auth" under the tab "Consent Screen" - https://console.developers.google.com/project/[your-project-id]/apiui/consent

looks like this:

[image: Consent Screen]

Following the [JSP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/ui_and_code), using the code

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
String loginUrl = userService.createLoginURL(req.getRequestURI())
```

redirects users to a login screen that looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

This UI is very dated. I'm seeing a noticeable increase in the number of users who get to this page and do not complete the login compared to when I was using the Javascript API.

Is there a newer UI that I'm missing, or a way to sign users in that is just as easy that has a better UI?

Answer (score 0):

In the new console you have the option to personalize to some extend the consent screen, other than that, I don't think there is much you can do.

Just replace [YourAppID] with your actual app id.

https://console.developers.google.com/project/[YourAppID]/apiui/consent

Comment: That's the weird part - the consent screen I see in the console is not the one that is created from the code from [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/ui_and_code): userService.createLoginURL(request.getRequestURI()).

Comment: You cannot code a consent screen if you want to use their user service. You can only change the information in the console so that the consent screen they provide has some custom information.

Comment: There wasn't enough room in the comment section to explain, so I edited the original question. 

Short answer: the code in the [JSP docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/ui_and_code) is not showing the consent screen from the Dev Console. That's the one I'm hoping for! It's showing a much more dated consent/login screen. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: have you found any solution yet?